# CI/CD Github Action with Azure Success but can not access to the API

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, github-actions, .net-5

I don't know why I do everything success full but I can't access the API, I really don't know why is it...

I have a default created.NET 5 Web API like this:
[image]

The ci-cd.yaml file:

```
name: Continuous Integration and Deployment

on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  DOTNET_VERSION: '5.0.x'
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: first-web-api

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out code ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Setup .NET 5 
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}
      
      - name: Restore dependencies ⌚
        run: dotnet restore

      - name: Build app 
        run: dotnet build -c Release --no-restore

      - name: Run automated tests 
        run: dotnet test -c Release --no-build
      
      - name: Publish app 
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ./out

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App 
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with: 
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_SECRET }}
          package: ./out
```

This is my azure app service (.net 5, linux operation)
[image]

After config and push everything is success like this:
[image]

But when I try to access the API weatherforecast it says not found:
[image]

Comment: What happens when you issue a call to the API via Postman (or some other API client tester)?